# de Moivre's theorem and square root of $(1-i)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am doing some exercise question on de Moivre's theorem and came across this question asking to find the square root of $1-i$.

My working are as follows:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
z^2 &=& \omega \\
&=& 1-i \\
|\omega| &=& \sqrt2 \\
\arg \omega &=& \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac11\right) \\
&=& \dfrac\pi4
\end{array}$$
$|w|=\sqrt 2$

Now as the vector is in the 4th quadrant I get $\arg \omega = \dfrac{7\pi}{4}$.

Then:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
w^{\frac{1}{2}} &=& \sqrt[4]2 e^{\frac{7i\pi}8} \\
z &=& \pm \sqrt[4]2\left[\cos\left(\dfrac{7\pi}{8}\right) + i \sin \left(\dfrac{7\pi}{8}\right)\right]
\end{array}$$

But the book give the ans as:

$$z = \pm \sqrt[4]2 \left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) + i \sin \left(\dfrac{\pi}{8}\right)\right]$$

The only way I can see the answer to be true is to take the angle clockwise from the positive x-axis. But I was under the impression that you always take the angle from the positive x axis in the anti-clockwise direction.

Comment: Why is the vector in the 4th quadr**a**nt?

Comment: Because i runs along the y axis so it would be in the fouth quadtrant

Comment: Do you mean that $(1-i)$ is in the fourth quadrant or $\sqrt{1-i}$ is in the fourth quadrant?

Comment: $1-i$ is in the fouth

Comment: I think your answer is right.

Comment: So why is the book giving it in that forum, unless it is looking for pricible root but it dose not state that.

Comment: $\pm\sqrt[4]2\left[\cos\left(\frac\pi8\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi8\right)\right]$ is wrong. An alternate correct answer would be $\pm\sqrt[4]2\left[\cos\left(\frac\pi8\right)-i\sin\left(\frac\pi8\right)\right]$

Comment: Your computation of $\arg\omega$ is wrong, in fact, $$\omega=\arctan\left(\frac{-1}1\right)=-\frac\pi4$$